# Badge Suggestions: Student Becomes Master + Continuing Education

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Two inverse (but not mutually exclusive) badges each of which could have representations at bronze/silver/gold levels. Although the descriptions say "for any tag" - the badges themselves would be 1-time (not per tag).

**Student Becomes Master:**

After receiving X upvotes on Questions in any tag, receive Y upvotes on Answers in that tag

**Continuing Education:**

After receiving X upvotes on Answers for any tag, receive Y upvotes on Questions for that tag.

Comment: In the long run, won't this just be equivalent to "participated heavily in at least one tag" for all users who aren't exclusively askers or exclusively answerers?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define "participated heavily". If a Gold badge required 1000/1000, then "in the long run" means that a user who alternates questions and answers and gets equal votes on each will earn both badges when they hit 2000/2000. For a "participated heavily" badge (where participation required both Q & A) I would suggest reaching X upvotes in a single tag with at least 25% being Questions and 25% being Answers.